# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf automatically appends , in model class property

Tags: spring-thymeleaf

Today I am facing a strange issue. I am using thymeleaf in combination with spring boot. I have number of forms in my application and all of them working fine expect for one form where I have model with nested classes. Whenever I save the form which has this nested structure, I receive the model class where some properties automatically has , appended to it (Not every property: please refer to screenshots below). I checked the network tab of browser the FormData in post request looks fine. But somehow in the middle it appends the comma. Check the companyname column for reference. The number of comma increases by 2 everytime I open the record in editmode and save again. So this means in the middle somewhere append is happening not setvalue.

Edit: I am using Lombok for auto getter and setters. Could this be a problem?

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MemberDTO extends StatusDTO {
    private long id;
    private String memberno;
    private String fileno;
    private String title;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String sowo;
    private String fathertitle;
    private String fathername;
    private String dob;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date membersince;
    private String mobileno;
    private String emailid;
    private String panno;
    private String aadhaarno;
    private String voteridno;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date retirementdate;
    private String income;
    private ResidenceDetails residencedetails;
    private OfficeDetails officedetails;
    private AuthorityAddressDTO authority;
    private BankDetailsDTO bank;
}

@Data
public class OfficeDetails {
    private String companyname;
    private String manager;
    private String address;
    private int state;
    private String pincode;
    private String department;
    private String designation;
    private String employeeid;
    private String pfno;
}
```

**Endpoint in MemberController**

```
@PostMapping(AppRoute.UPDATE_MEMBER)
    public String updateMemberDetails(@ModelAttribute(Attr.MEMBER) MemberDTO memberDTO, Model model, HttpSession session) {
        String sessionToken = session.getAttribute(Arbit.Session.FORM_TOKEN).toString();
        memberDTO = memberService.updateMember(memberDTO, sessionToken, prefs.getSession().getChildid());
        if(memberDTO.getStatuscode() == 200){
            session.setAttribute(Arbit.Session.FORM_TOKEN, memberDTO.getFormtoken());
        }
        model.addAttribute(Attr.ACTION, AppRoute.UPDATE_MEMBER);
        model.addAttribute(Attr.MEMBER, memberDTO);
        model.addAttribute(Attr.USER_PREFS, prefs);
        model.addAttribute(Attr.POPUP_OPTIONS, popupOptionService.getMemberPageOptions());
        setViewName(model, Attr.MEMBER);
        return AppRoute.VIEW_MANAGER + AppRoute.INIT_MEMBER;
    }
```

**Network Tab of Browser**

[image]

**Data Received on Endpoint in Model**

[image]

**authority and bank both are nested classes but in authority we can see commas and in bank it is fine**

[image]

**Payload in POST request**

[image]

Comment: I think it is a bug in thymeleaf. Without nested model class it is working fine.